# Certain Pages in my Express/EJS app get stuck on "Waiting for localhost..."

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm building an Node/Express/EJS app, and most pages that display data being passed through my EJS templates get stuck in "Waiting for localhost..."

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var data   = require("./data/info.json");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

//Index Route
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});

//Profile Route
app.get("/profiles", function(req, res){
    res.render("profiles");
});

//Indivual Routes
app.get("/profiles/test", function(req, res){
    res.render("template", {data: data})
});


app.get("/idea", function(req, res){
    res.render("idea", {data: data})
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Has Started on Port 3000");
});
```

Currently the Index and Profile page load fine, but 9/10 times the 'idea' and 'test' page get stuck on the "Waiting for localhost..."

Any advice/suggestions would be very appreciated.

EDIT: Included Data JSON and Idea Template
Data JSON

```
{ Character:
   { LastChanged: '2018-04-06T10:28:14.857',
     NotPersisted: 'false',
     FileName: 'Char4.xml',
     Name: '',
     Key: 'c521cd46-ab33-431a-8b04-a110f59e4968',
     Description:
      { CharName: 'Next PC',
        PlayerName: 'Next PC',
        GenderValue: 'cdgMale',
        Age: '37',
        Height: '6\'0"',
        Build: 'Slim',
        Hair: 'Long  Black',
        Eyes: 'Brown',
        Gender: 'Male' },
     Characteristics: { CharCharacteristic: [Array] },
     Motivations: { CharMotivation: [Object] },
     Specializations: { CharSpecialization: [Object] },
     ForcePowers: '',
     SigAbilities: '',
     Skills: { CharSkill: [Array] },
     ObOptions: { StartingSize: '10', Plus10XP: 'true' },
     Obligations: { CharObligation: [Array] },
     DutOptions: { StartingSize: '5' },
     Duties: '',
     Experience: { ExperienceRanks: [Object], UsedExperience: '100' },
     Attributes:
      { SoakValue: [Object],
        WoundThreshold: [Object],
        StrainThreshold: [Object],
        DefenseRanged: '',
        DefenseMelee: '',
        ForceRating: '' },
     Species:
      { SpeciesKey: 'KYUZO',
        SubSpeciesKey: '',
        SelectedOptions: [Object] },
     Career:
      { CareerKey: 'SOLDIER',
        StartingSpecKey: 'SHARPSHOOTER',
        CareerSkills: [Object],
        CareerSpecSkills: [Object] },
     Class: { ClassKey: 'PRIVFEW' },
     Hook: { HookKey: 'OPP' },
     Attitude: { AttitudeKey: 'ANCIENTRELIGION' },
     Weapons: { CharWeapon: [Array] },
     Armor: { CharArmor: [Object] },
     Gear: '',
     Vehicles: '',
     NPCs: '',
     SummaryPriorities: '',
     Story: '',
     Credits: '500',
     Morality: { MoralityValue: '50' },
     Grants: { UseGrants: 'false' },
     Rigger:
      { VehicleKey: '',
        WeaponIndex: '-1',
        custRigger: '',
        MaxSilhouette: '0' },
     Schematics: '',
     UseGrants: 'false',
     AutoRecalc: 'true',
     '_xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
     '_xmlns:xsd': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' } }
```

Idea Template

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<% var json = data['Character']['Skills']['CharSkill'] %>
<div class="containter">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <th>Skill</th>
                    <th>Rank</th>
                    <% for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++ ){ %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= data['Character']['Skills']['CharSkill'][i]['Key'] %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <% var skillstr = JSON.stringify(data['Character']['Skills']['CharSkill'][i]['Rank']); %>
                                <% var skill = skillstr.replace(/\D/g, ''); %>
                                <% var skillsum = 0;%>
                                <% while (skill) { skillsum += skill % 10; sw = Math.floor(skill / 10); } %>
                                <%= skillsum %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Edit2: I've been testing it and the problem only arises when I add

```
<% var skillsum = 0;%>
<% while (skill) { skillsum += skill % 10; sw = Math.floor(skill / 10); } %>
```

Before I add that everything works as intended.

Comment: try to console log the data in /idea call  before res.render of course and tell me what do you see

Comment: it logged the entire json object I'm passing through.

Comment: Your data object does not contain any array of object so i think you should probably use this code instead your own one: 
var json = data.Character.Skills.CharSkill

Comment: The information was still passed through as before, but that page still get stuck on "waiting for localhost..."

Comment: I just added another edit, the app works until I add those two lines in.

Comment: you should verify if tha array charSkill contain any item with only caracteres because skillstr.replace(/\D/g, ''); will return undefined if it found not numeric caractere

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering without passing data. If it fails, problem is with data.

Comment: I jsut added the data I'm trying to pass through as well as the code for the idea page template